# NodeJs - sockets io - client system auto reconnect

Tags: node.js, sockets, io, client, reconnect

I want to create a client of socket's io server, where in x and x seconds try make a connection to socket's io server, to verify is server is already up.

What i have in client:

src="http://localhost:90/socket.io/socket.io.js" - load script

```
var serverStatus = recconectToServer();

        setInterval(function(){

            if (serverStatus) {
                $(".results-server").append("<p style='color:green; width:100%; float:left;'>connection up.</p>");
            } else {
                recconectToServer();
            }
        },3000);


        function recconectToServer() {
            $(".results-server").append("<p style='color:orange; width:100%; float:left;'>try connection.</p>");
            try {
                var socket = new io.connect("http://localhost:90");
                return true;
            } catch(err) {
                $(".results-server").append("<p style='color:red; width:100%; float:left;'>server down.</p>");
                console.log(" Erro = "+ err);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**Situations:**

IF client try to connect when server is down i receive this message:
"ReferenceError: io is not defined"

That is normal because server is down, then i start server and client when try make connection (without refresh page) continues receive this message "ReferenceError: io is not defined"

But why this happen?

NOTE: If i execute refresh client page, when server is running, client connect without any problem.

**UPDATED:**
Real problem: the event connected_failed from sockets.io dont work, like others questions that exist in stackoverflow. So for resolve this i did the next solution:

My solution:

```
<script src="http://localhost:90/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            /**
            * timer that try make a new connection to node server
            */
            setInterval(function(){
                if (autoReconnect()) {
                    window.location.href="client.html";
                } else {
                    autoReconnect();
                }
            },5000);

            /**
            * This functions try make connection to node server
            */
            function autoReconnect(){
                try {
                    $.getScript("http://localhost:90/socket.io/socket.io.js");
                    var socket = new io.connect('http://localhost:90');
                    return true;
                } catch(err) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    </script>
```

Conclusion:
   When server become up again, will be redirect to other page, where continue the initial process.

I don't know if this is the best solution, if someone have one better, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

When your server is down, you cannot serve the client script for socket.io. Therefore io is not defined.
The reconnect will not work because the client never tries to reload the client script.
When the server is already running, the client script can be accessed and io is defined.
Therefore you should extend your reconnectToServer function to try to reload the client script if neccessary, perhaps something like

```
if(io === undefined)
    $(".results-server").append("<script src=\"http://localhost:90/socket.io/socket.io.js\"");
```

Comment: carlptr, like you said is the logic, but to get the sockets.io.js i need to used the getScript from jquery. $.getScript("http://localhost:90/socket.io/socket.io.js");